# Can C([0,1]) be written as a countable union of compact sets?

Tags: functional-analysis

Let $X=C([0,1])$ be the Banach space of continuous real valued functions on $[0,1]$ (with the $\sup$-norm).

I am wondering if $X$ can be written as a countable union of compact sets $K_1 \subset K_2\subset K_3 \dots$?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

No.

1. If $X$ is an infinite-dimensional Banach space then the closed unit ball is not compact.
2. Apply the [Baire Category Theorem](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Baire_category_theorem) to $X = \bigcup_{n=1}^\infty K_n$ to find an open set with compact closure.
3. Combine 1. and 2. to derive a contradiction.

Comment: Thanks for the quick answer. Could you explain more the second point? Which version of the Baire Category theorem are you using and how does it imply $\bigcup K_n$ is locally compact?

Comment: The following version of Baire: If a complete metric space is written as a countable union of closed sets, then at least one of them has non-empty interior. Suppose the interior of $K_n$ is nonempty, so it contains a small open ball $B_r(x_0)$ whose closure is compact since it is contained in $K_n$. Translate $x_0$ to zero, scale with $1/r$ to deduce that the closed unit ball is compact.